# PHP returned code not showing up, but it used to

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I run a website for my church. In a database on the server, we store all of the newest sermons' information so that when a user clicks a button on the first page, the newest sermons will show up in a div. For a long time, everything was working just great, but now, the returned code just doesn't show up.

The weird thing is, if I open the page in Google Chrome and hit "Inspect Element" over the div, the returned code just appears. It looks perfect... After I have done that, clicking on the button will again  load the info from the database and it will show up; if I refresh the page, however, the returned stuff goes away again until I inspect the element.

Try it for yourself [here](http://faithlifefellowship.us). Click the orange button labeled "New Message."

NOTE:

- The div that pops up is id **navNew**
- The background transparent div that pops up is id **navBackground**
- Within the div id navNew, I have a p id **navNewBody** that holds the information returned by the get PHP page below.

My code for the PHP getter page:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('domain', 'username', 'password'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

mysql_select_db(flf);

$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new");
$first = mysql_num_rows($r);

$last = $first - 20;
echo '<p class="NavHead">New Sermons<br/><table width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';

$ind = 0;

while($first > $last){

$me=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new WHERE id='" . $first . "'"));
$name = $me["name"];
$row = 21-$ind;
echo '<tr id="row' . $row . '" class="navClosed" onclick="expand(' . "'" . 'row' . $row . "'" .  ',' . $row . ')"><td colspan="4">&nbsp;' . $name . '</td></tr><tr id="row' . $row . 'e" style="visibility: hidden" class="navOpenClosed" onclick="dismiss(' . "'" . 'row' . $row . "'" . ')"></tr>';
$first = $first - 1;
$ind = $ind + 1;
}

echo "</table></p>";
?>
```

And here is the code I use to access the page (yes I imported jQuery):

```
function retNew(){
    document.getElementById("navNewBody").innerHTML = '<span class="NavHead"><p align="center">Loading...Please Wait...<br/><br/><br/><img src="Sermons/Style/Loading.gif" /></p></span>';
    document.getElementById("navNew").style.visibility = "visible";      

    $("#navNewBody").load("retNew.php");
}
```

What's wrong? It just doesn't make sense to me. I set the z-index to 10,000,000 and nothing happened. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should put quotes around `flf` if it's the name of your db: `mysql_select_db('flf');`. That won't fix your issue, so this is just a comment, but you really should change that.

Comment: You have even more problems - click on one of the sermons, let it load, close to popup. It stays on top of everything.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I wasn't going to worry about that until I got this issue fixed

Comment: Actually, it is not clear what `the weird thing` is.. I've clicked on the orange button, popup with loaded data appears. What is wrong exactly and why do you need 'inspect element'?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong but what about turning the non-jQuery code to jQuery?  Maybe there's an inter-op issue here:

`function retNew(){
    var navNewBody = $("navNewBody");
    navNewBody.append('<span class="NavHead"><p align="center">Loading...Please Wait...<br/><br/><br/><img src="Sermons/Style/Loading.gif" /></p></span>');
    $("navNew").show();      

    navNewBody.load("retNew.php");
}​`

Comment: wait...so the popup loads the code when you click on it? When I do, I just see a blank black div until I hit inspect element...

Comment: Yep, it loads. There is a delay, looks like the server is slightly overloaded, but everything shows up.

Comment: Huh, it loads for me too now...Ok then. Thanks everyone for your help. Guess it was just a temporary glitch in the system. I appreciate it!

Comment: Couple of other hints - your popup is replacing the title of the page with some html code. It is also better to fix position of the close button, so that you can hit even after scrolling down.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for that. Do you have any ideas how Apple does it, you know with the button kind of off of the corner of the div?

Comment: It is simple, if the parent div has fixed, relative or absolute position, then the absolute position of its children is counted from the parent. So `<div style='position:relative'><img src='image.jpg' style='position:absolute; right: -20px; top: -20px;'>Some content</div>` will place an image to the right top edge of the parent div.

Comment: Umm...problem, the stuff isn't loading again. I still have to press Inspect element to get the table to show up.

Comment: An alert on EVERY page load telling me to switch browsers? Shoot me now.

Comment: Only on the home page, again a bridge to cross after I get this issue fixed.

Comment: get rid of visibility. You have display: block; display: none which are better. at first display: none, when you need it - change to block or use jQuery's show() function

Comment: Tried display, didn't work. The functions didn't even run

Comment: Because a few more things should be replaced - your script is also based on the visibility property. Btw, you could rewrite it as `function retNew(){
    $('#navNewBody').html('<div class="NavHead"><p align="center">Loading...Please Wait...<br/><br/><br/><img src="Sermons/Style/Loading.gif" /></p></div>').load('retNew.php');
    $('#navNew').fadeIn();     
}` And remember - you can not use p tag inside of span - p is block tag and span is inline one. fadeIn is a nice transition, but it works with display only.

Comment: Okay, another update, if I quit Chrome and reopen it, the first time I navigate to the page it works just fine, but as soon I refresh it's gone.

Comment: Oh cool! That worked! Thanks Cheery! You should post an answer with that method change so I can give you +rep!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you visibility is messing with the content. Try to use this load.

```
function retNew(){
   $('#navNewBody').html('<div class="NavHead"><p align="center">Text</p></div>')
                   .load('retNew.php');
   $('#navNew').fadeIn();      
}
```

As of the close button, in your case it should be something like that:

```
<div id="navNew">
  <a class="LargeNameU" onclick="offNavNew();return false;" 
            style='position:fixed; z-index: 1000; right:0px;top:0px'>
       <img src="Sermons/Style/x.png" border='0'>
  </a>
<p align="center" style="z-index:10000000" id="navNewBody">
```

and so on. Your .navNew already has a fixed position.

Answer (score 1):

The visibility property has some very weird problems. I would recommend using `display` instead. The only difference between the two is that display removes the element entirely when it's set to `none`, while visibility just essentially makes the element invisible (but still leaves a space in the page where the element was).